# Design database Firebase for quote app

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a quotes application which works with SQL database and I want to move to a Firebase Database. Since SQL database is a relational database, I am confused with the correct structure for the application.

In the SQL Database I am using three tables:

-category

-author

-quotes

Authors
Categories
Quotes

Each quote has an Author and a Category so the user gets to see a list of authors and can view all quotes by a particular author. He can also see a list of categories and can view all quotes associated with a particular category.

So Quotes table has two foreign keys the reference to Authors table primary key and Categories table primary key.

Can anyone help me out the best possible structure of my application?

tnx

Comment: but how can I realize this relational database because I do not know how to relate it with firebase

Comment: @akshay_shahane What product are you referring to? If you mean Cloud Firestore, that is *not* a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extremely simple way to achieve this. Following is the data structure you'll require for your specification

[image]

You can easily reference the quotes based on categories and by querying through firebaseDB. You can do that by

`Database.Database().child(quotes).childOrderBy("Category-tag").observe()`

Similarly you can fetch the list of authors by their `uid`.

Hope you found this helpful

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This a solution for structuring the Firebase database for your quotes application:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
    |     |
    |     --- uid1
    |          |
    |          --- authors
    |          |      |
    |          |      --- authorId1: true
    |          |      |
    |          |      --- authorId2: true
    |          |
    |          --- categories
    |                 |
    |                 --- categoryId1: true
    |                 |
    |                 --- categoryId2: true
    |
    --- categories
    |     |
    |     --- categoryId1
    |             |
    |             --- quoteId1: true
    |             |
    |             --- quoteId2: true
    |
    --- authors
    |     |
    |     --- authorId1
    |            |
    |            --- quotes
    |                   |
    |                   --- quoteId1: true
    |                   |
    |                   --- quoteId2: true
    |                  
    |
    --- quotes
          |
          --- quoteId1
                 |
                 --- categoryId1: true
                 |
                 --- authorId1: true
```

I have not included in this database structure the details like, names of the author, name of category and other such details, so you can focus on the relations between Firebase nodes. Using this database structure, you can do the following operations to see:

- All quotes
- All quotes that belong to a single author
- All quotes that belong to a single category
- All quotes that belong to a particular author and a particular category
- All categories
- All authors

In the end, I recomand you see this series of tutorials: [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for a better understanding.